# Javascript innerHTML is not changing HTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

Here is my code : https://gist.github.com/mhassain/243f10f66ebbbef777b1d374d3125798

Here are line 52 & 53:

```
document.getElementById('countryTitle').innerHTML       = data.name;
document.getElementById('countryDetailInfo').innerHTML  = html;
```

In Line 52 HTML content is changed, but in Line 53, content is not changed!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: The **only** reasons the `document.getElementById('countryDetailInfo').innerHTML  = html;` line wouldn't (seem to) work are: 1. There is no element with that ID as of when you run that line, so it throws an error; 2. `html` already contains the same thing that's in the element; or 3. Something else changes it again later, and you don't notice it change and then change back. (Of course, since I put "only" in bold, someone's going to come up with a #4 or even #5... :-) )

Answer (score 1):

It actually changes the html. You don't see it because it's at the bottom. Scroll to the bottom of the page and you'll see it.

Comment: thanks a lot. Removed class h-100 and now the change is visible now. :)